# Data doesn't insert , but no error is shown

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I was trying to create a sign up page using xampp server.I wrote a php code but data doesn't insert in the database,and even no error is shown.I can'y find out the problem.I checked if my database is connected or not.It is connected because I tried to recheck by typing wrong code then error message pops up on the screen.My code is given below

enter code here

help me out with this.where is the problem actually I can't figure.    I was trying to create a sign up page using xampp server.I wrote a php code but data doesn't insert in the database,and even no error is shown.I can'y find out the problem.I checked if my database is connected or not.It is connected because I tried to recheck by typing wrong code then error message pops up on the screen.My code is given below

```
<?php include("connect.php"); ?>

<?php
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declraing variable to prevent error!
$un = "";//username
$em = "";//email
$pswd = "";//password
$pswd2 = "";//password2
$u_check = "";//check if username exists
//registration form
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);

if ($reg){
    if($em){
        //check if user already exists
        $u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$un'");
        //count the amount of rows where username=$un
        $check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
        if($check==0){
            //check all of the fields have been filled in
            if($un&&$em&&$pswd&&$pswd2){

                //check that passwords match
                `if($pswd==$pswd2){
                     if(strlen($un)>=30){
                         echo "the maximum limit for username is 30 characters!";
                     }
                     else
                    {
                        if(strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd2)>30){
                            echo "your password must be 6 to 30 characters long!";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //encrypt password and password2 using md5 before sending to database
                            $pswd = md5($pswd);
                            $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('','$un','$em','$pswd')");
                            die("<h2>Welcome to Invite!<h2>Login to your account to get started!");
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else{
                    echo "your password do not match!";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "please fill up all the fields";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "username already taken!";
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>register page</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="themes/assets/ico/icon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <img src="back.jpg" height="619px" width="1366px">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container">

            <h1>Sign Up Form</h1>

            <form class="form">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Name">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">xxxxx@xxx.com
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">password must contain atleast six characters

                <input type="password" name="password2 " placeholder="Re-type Password">confirm your password<br>

                <button type="submit" name="reg" id="register-button">Sign Up!
                </button>

            </form>

        </div>

        <ul class="bg-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `mysqli`

Comment: What is the code for connect.php?

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","ntsuhi6") or die("error!");
mysql_select_db("invite") or die("error2!");
?>

Comment: Here    `if($pswd==$pswd2){     you have a single quote. Remove that first

Comment: Don't use `@` this bad way. For check exist index you can use `empty()`

Comment: @Naumov a variable can be `empty()` and still hold a valid value, such as `""`, `0`, or `"0"`.

Comment: isset would be better in that case

Comment: Simple example `!empty($var)?"":$var` but this too bad way you can develop function for check exist key and return value if value isset in post or return null if key not exist

Comment: @Jester you trust isset better

Comment: @Naumov better? i use both myself, they just do different things. empty also accepts empty variables where as isset doesn't. `$var = 0;` would make `empty($var);` be true but `!isset($var);` would give false cause it is set, it's just 0

Comment: i added multiple echo and i also corrected my code but still not a single thing shows up!

Comment: edit the code in your question as well so we know how the code looks now ^^

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should turn on error_reporting at the start of the php file, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
```

second of all you have to check manually for MySQL errors, it won't show them automatically:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('','$un','$em','$pswd')");
if(!query) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

i'd like to also point that you have a backtick at the start of your if

```
//check that passwords match
            `if($pswd==$pswd2){
                 if(strlen($un)>=30){
```

Also like robert said, you should switch over to mysqli, mysql methods are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: `mysql_` functions are **removed** in PHP 7. Which means that the code simply will not work in PHP 7.

Comment: i corrected the php part.but still it doesn't work.and still no error is given

Comment: this would mean that your code simply never arrives at the else case in which your insert is. try adding multiple `echo "case 1";`, case 2 e.t.c in the different if and else's and see which path it takes. This way you can pin point whether one of your variables or if statements is not as you expect it to be. you can also `echo` or `print_r` the variables themself and see if they are what you expect

Comment: i added multiple echo but still not a single thing shows up!

Comment: that would mean it doesn't pass anything? mmm it might not show up cause you're echoing before you open the html. you could move the html, the head and the opening of the body in front of your php code

Comment: i also didi that! nothing happens ...i don't know what is the problem with this code!

Comment: instead of echoing you should probably concatenate it to a string variable. set $teststring and then keep adding to it
`$teststring = $teststring."case1 ";` then echo the string within div container, most likely your css prevents the rest from showing up i guess, you can test this by just echoing something right next to a piece of text that you can read. below your header (<h1>Sign Up Form</h1>) for example

Comment: i don't know what you mean by that you should be able to echo a string somewhere where you can see it visibly. if you found a place then you can make up a variable string and figure out what goes wrong that way. remember the code does exactly what it should, it's always human error ;')

Comment: true! it's always human error! But my bad! :( I can't find the problem as well as I can't edit my question. so i have no other way to show you my code.besides I am actually a new coder and new to this site. aaarrrghhh everything's messed up! sorry for my awkward behaviour but its depressing!

Comment: I made a chatroom for us, you can join and we can continue there.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108111/conversation-between-khadiza-kobra-and-jester

Comment: I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there -_-

Comment: aah :s whatever just post what you want in the comments. so did you manage to echo something somewhere where it's visible for you?\

Comment: no its awkward! can I have your email ID..if that is not a problem! :) or am I way too much straight forward?

Comment: my email id or my email adres? ;') i'll post it in the chat, you can read it there

Comment: lol! sorry my mistake! I have sent you an email.plz check! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //check that passwords match
  remove this -------->`if($pswd==$pswd2){
                         if(strlen($un)>=30){
                             echo "the maximum limit for username is 30 characters!";
                         }
```